# IPv6 configuration - cannot ping

Tags: ip, ipv6

I am trying to configure IPv6 network first time in my live.

I have got on my main server following interfaces:

```
br1   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 66:ea:5c:99:08:f5  
      inet addr:192.168.0.1  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::64ea:5cff:fe99:8f5/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:6 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:636 (636.0 B)

eth0  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:25:90:7a:1b:9c  
      inet addr:87.106.73.113  Bcast:87.106.73.113  Mask:255.255.255.255
      inet6 addr: 2001:8d8:8f3:5700::15:7260/64 Scope:Global
      inet6 addr: fe80::225:90ff:fe7a:1b9c/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:64808 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:54414 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:36396559 (34.7 MiB)  TX bytes:32748716 (31.2 MiB)
      Memory:fb920000-fb940000
```

and on the virtual server (using xen on main one)

```
eth0  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:16:3e:5b:e3:4d  
      inet addr:192.168.0.4  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::216:3eff:fe5b:e34d/64 Scope:Link
      inet6 addr: 2001:8d8:8f3:579c:517e:a55a:f29f:d4c1/64 Scope:Global
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:4 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:352 (352.0 B)  TX bytes:676 (676.0 B)
      Interrupt:25
```

I have tried add routing on the virtual server by

```
ip -6 route add default via 2001:8d8:8f3:5700::15:7260 dev eth0
```

by I still cannot ping via IPv6 (of course I can ping via IPv4).

The virtual server needs to be available from outside and the IPv6 it has to be the external IP for server.

How should I actually configure all routing etc to get this working?

Comment: Did you set up a route to the guest bridge on the host?

Comment: No. Should I run this command on main server `ip -6 route add 2001:8d8:8f3:579c:517e:a55a:f29f:d4c1` or how should I do it? Apologize for this question but it is just first time when I am setting this up.

Comment: Your virtual server is in `2001:8d8:8f3:579c::/64` and your default gateway is in `2001:8d8:8f3:5700::/64`. That can never work. Can you include a network diagram? Is the host meant to route or bridge the network?

Comment: @Sander Steffann, I even have not checked that this are in different network after getting the IP from my hoster. I just got from them another IP which is 2001:8d8:8f3:5700:0:0:15:7280. I have changed the IPv6 on virtual server to it but it is still not working. It suppose to route the network.

Answer (score 2):

A traceroute to `2001:8d8:8f3:579c:517e:a55a:f29f:d4c1` shows me this:

```
 3  2001:470:0:69::1  68.251 ms  33.776 ms  34.043 ms
 4  2001:7f8::2170:0:2  36.286 ms  39.953 ms  37.055 ms
 5  2001:8d8:0:2::95  44.412 ms  44.052 ms  44.152 ms
 6  2001:8d8:0:2::d2  41.018 ms  52.907 ms  47.670 ms
 7  2001:8d8:0:9::e7  48.028 ms  46.261 ms  46.272 ms
 8  2001:8d8:0:11::36:a  46.855 ms  47.401 ms  47.211 ms
 9  2001:8d8:8f3:5700::15:7260  46.468 ms  44.278 ms  44.522 ms
10  2001:8d8:0:11::36:a  45.445 ms  49.779 ms  48.461 ms
11  2001:8d8:8f3:5700::15:7260  47.882 ms  48.060 ms  48.372 ms
12  2001:8d8:0:11::36:a  47.653 ms  48.689 ms  48.367 ms
13  *  *  *
14  2001:8d8:0:11::36:a  48.760 ms  48.888 ms  49.037 ms
15  *  *  *
16  2001:8d8:0:11::36:a  48.238 ms  *  *
17  *  *  *
18  *  *  *
19  *  *  *
20  *  *  *
21  *  *  *
22  *  *  *
23  *  *  *
24  *  *  *
25  *  *  *
26  *  *  *
27  *  *  *
28  2001:8d8:0:11::36:a  47.350 ms  47.350 ms  51.596 ms
29  2001:8d8:8f3:5700::15:7260  48.272 ms  *  *
30  2001:8d8:0:11::36:a  47.516 ms  70.904 ms  70.969 ms
```

This shows very clearly that you have a routing loop. The routing loop goes between you main server and `2001:8d8:0:11::36:a`, which appears to be your gateway.

This means your server is not routing this prefix towards the VM but rather routes it back towards the gateway (presumably by using the default route).

This means you need to add `2001:8d8:8f3:579c::/64` as a directly attached route on the link towards the VM. One way of doing that would be to add `2001:8d8:8f3:579c::1/64` as an address on the host assigned to the interface facing towards the VM.

Comment: Nice one, well spotted!

Comment: I'm guessing that `br1` is the interface towards the virtual machines, so try to add `2001:8d8:8f3:579c::1/64` to that interface.